# Using systemd-networkd inside a podman container

Tags: docker, systemd, podman

The end goal is to have a macvlan interface set up within a Podman container. I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim
RUN apt-get --yes install systemd
RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

If I then run this in privileged mode (detached) and attach a shell to the running container (as root), I can set up a macvlan interface called `macvlan1` on the default tap interface using `iproute2`:

```
# apt install iproute2
# ip link add macvlan1 link tap0 type macvlan mode bridge
```

However, I want to avoid this, and I think it should be possible using `systemd-networkd`, but I'm not having much luck.  I've tried the following `.network` and `.netdev` files (which I have tested to work on my host machine):

```
### 99-test.network
[Match]
Name=tap0

[Network]
MACVLAN=macvlan1
```

```
### 99-test.netdev
[Match]
# Empty

[NetDev]
Name=macvlan1
Kind=macvlan

[MACVLAN]
Mode=bridge
```

I update my Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim
COPY 99-test.network /lib/systemd/network
COPY 99-test.netdev /lib/systemd/network
RUN apt-get --yes install systemd
RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
RUN systemctl enable systemd-networkd
CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

But when I start up the container, I see no macvlan interface created. If I look at the output of `systemctl status systemd-networkd` there are no logs or error messages suggesting that it's attempted to read the `.network` and `.netdev` files. The only clue I have is that when I run `networkctl` on my host machine, it shows the physical interfaces as `unmanaged` in the `SETUP` column whereas in the container, it shows all interfaces as `pending` (including for a manually-created macvlan interface).

Is what I'm trying to do possible with systemd in Podman? If not, why not?

Comment: A setup running systemd and trying to manually manage the network configuration sounds much more like a virtual machine to me; a Docker container is normally a wrapper around only a single process, and the container runtime normally manages the entire network environment (and a lot of other things systemd normally tries to handle).  Would a VM better meet your needs here?

Comment: I am aware that I'm abusing Docker containers a bit here. Thanks for your advice. but a VM is too heavyweight for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [`--driver macvlan`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-network-create.1.html#driver-d-driver) network (configurable with `--options`) outside the container as a [`podman network`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-network.1.html). Then "plug it in" to the [`podman container`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-container.1.html) with `--network <name>`.

To avoid manual setup steps, see also [Podman Quadlet](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-systemd.unit.5.html) usage with  `[Container]` `Network=<name>.network` and `[Network]` `Driver=macvlan` for augmented systemd unit files. (Note that Quadlet `*.network` units are completely separate from `systemd-networkd` `*.network` files.)

This way Podman resources and unit files are set up on the host, keeping the container light-weight. There is no need to install `systemd` in the container, which would then become "too heavy".

Also consider running the container and [macvlan network in rootless mode](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/18207), either as yourself or as systemd services from a separate unprivileged [`loginctl enable-linger`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6) user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something medium-weight, between virtual machine and container, consider [`systemd-nspawn`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-nspawn.html). Can be used to spawn "machines" from full distribution images, or minimal directories. With the machine in place, you can run individual commands, shells, or perform a full `--boot`.

This solution sets up and manages network interfaces from the host. You can spawn a new machine with [`--network-macvlan=<device>`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-nspawn.html#--network-macvlan=) to create a separate network.

Control the machine with [`machinectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/machinectl.html). You can `machinectl enable` to autostart `systemd-nspawn@.service`, which implies `--boot`.

Spawning a machine which uses systemd as PID 1 allows certain synergies. You can then use other systemd tools with `--machine` directly from the host machine. One example is [`systemctl --machine`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html#-M): `sudo systemctl --machine my-user@my-machine status`.